# Search engine in PHP with MySQL: Unable to search with more than a single keyword, gives PDOException Error

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I must say am still a baby when it comes to php and mysql, but am learning and improving everyday with you guys help.
Yeah I created a search engine in PHP with MySQL and to an extent, it is working, but the challenge that am having is that I get `PDOException` error message when i search with more than a single keyword like 'David Smith' but with 'David' or 'Smith' alone, i don't get any error.

Honestly I don't know where I got it all wrong. Am using wampserver `PDO db connection` for my Database. below is the sample of the code.

```
    //search button name and id is 'search'

    $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
        {
            for($x=0; $x<=0; $x++ ); 

            if($x==1)
                $construct .="UserID LIKE '%$search_each%' or Requestor LIKE '%$search_each%' or EmploymentType LIKE '%$search_each%'";
            else
                $construct .="AND UserID LIKE '%$search_each%' AND Requestor LIKE '%$search_each%' AND EmploymentType LIKE '%$search_each%'"; 
        }
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ".TBL_STUDENTS." WHERE $construct";
    $result = $database->connection->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array($construct));
```

Like i said, it works fine when i search with a single keyword like 'David' but i get error when i search with something like 'David Smith'.

Below is the error message that I do get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception '`PDOException`' with message '`SQLSTATE[42000]`:
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'UserID LIKE '%Gift%' or Requestor LIKE `%Gift%` or EmploymentType LIKE `%Gift%` at line 3'
in `C:\wamp\www\ccnl\script\search_db.php` on line 108
```

The line is this code below

```
$result->execute(array($construct));
```

Comment: I think it must be `AND UserID` instead of `UserID`

Comment: Thanks Perry for the effort, but i still get the same erro when i removed the AND in front of UserID

Comment: You should echo your construct sql and try it in phpMyAdmin.   Echoing sql is the quickest way to debug it as errors rapidly become obvious.  FWIIW, try a space at the start of your strings vis $construct.=" AND...  as sql will ignore spaces but reject words that run together.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array, then imploding it:-

```
//search button name and id is 'search'

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$construct = array();

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $construct[] =" (UserID LIKE '%$search_each%' or Requestor LIKE '%$search_each%' or EmploymentType LIKE '%$search_each%') ";
}
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ".TBL_STUDENTS." WHERE ".implode(" OR ", $construct);
$result = $database->connection->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array($construct));
```

Comment: Hi Kickstart, i just tried using an array with the instance you gave, but i got the following errors. 1) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\ccnl\script\search_db.php on line 100, and line code is $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ".TBL_PRODUCT_ORDER." WHERE $construct"; (2) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'' in C:\wamp\www\ccnl\script\search_db.php on line 102, and the line code is $result->execute(array($construct));

Comment: Please guys am still stocked, any help? Thanks

Comment: Did you change line 100 to use implode on $construct? The error looks like you have just concatenated the array $construct onto the end of the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Put a space

```
$construct .="AND Use
```

in front of AND like this:

```
$construct .=" AND Use
```